# state inside each flatlist component not being remembered

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I have this flatlist which lists all the jobs,uponclick we are taken to a Job details page where you can apply to the job. On apply, the button name changes to "applied" and it is disabled. I got this part working,. however when I go back to homepage and click on the same job again, the button is clickable and still says "apply now", instead of "applied". Does this have anything to do with flatlist and navigation?

Home.js:

```
export default function Home(params) {
    const{ navigation}=params;
    ...

    return(

       <FlatList
        data={getCompanies(companies, filter)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return( 
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ navigation.navigate('Job Details',item)}}>
          <View style={styles.listingCard}>
            <View style={styles.listingCardBody}>
            <Text style={styles.listingCardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listingCardDescription}>
               Here is a really simple description from {item.title} about the
                role being advertized...
            </Text>
           </View>
         </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
       );        
    }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => { return item.id; }}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
  />



);}
```

Job Details:

```
function Jobdetails({route, navigation}){

    const{ title, Category, rateHourly, responsibilities,location, postedBy,id,jobOverview, jobType, startDate, endDate, latitude, longitude}= route.params;

    const [ butText, setButText] = useState("Apply Now");
    const [ clickable, setClickable ]= useState(false);

 <TouchableOpacity disabled={ clickable } style={page.button} onPress={()=>{
      
     //apply() works fine
      apply(id).then(async (result)=>{
      if(result.succeeded()){
        setButText('Application Successful!');
        setClickable(true);
      }
  });
 }}>
    <Text style={page.text}>{ butText }</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Why isn't 'clickable' value being remembered by the app?

Comment: Try putting the `clickable` usestate hook in the `Home.js` and pass `setClickable` as the prop, not `clickable` to job details

Comment: how will I access value of clickable in job details then

Comment: You may have to create a react context outside both compoments

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment,

Create a CLickableContext.js with

```
import { createContext } from "react";   

export const CLickableContext= createContext(null);
```

On a component higher up in your app, set up the provider with the usestate hook.

```
import { CLickableContext} from "../CLickableContext";

...

const [clickable, setClickable] = useState(false);

...

<CLickableContext.Provider value={{ clickable, setClickable }}>
   <YourApp/>
</CLickableContext.Provider>
```

Then include the context in any compenent throughout the app

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CLickableContext} from "../CLickableContext";

//Home.js
export default function Home(params) {
    const { clickable, setClickable  } = useContext(CLickableContext);
    const{ navigation}=params;
    ...

    return(

       <FlatList
        data={getCompanies(companies, filter)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return( 
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ navigation.navigate('Job Details',item)}}>
          <View style={styles.listingCard}>
            <View style={styles.listingCardBody}>
            <Text style={styles.listingCardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listingCardDescription}>
               Here is a really simple description from {item.title} about the
                role being advertized...
            </Text>
           </View>
         </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
       );        
    }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => { return item.id; }}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
  />



);}
```

And

```
//Jobdetails.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CLickableContext} from "../CLickableContext";

function Jobdetails({route, navigation}){
    const { clickable, setClickable  } = useContext(CLickableContext);
    const{ title, Category, rateHourly, responsibilities,location, postedBy,id,jobOverview, jobType, startDate, endDate, latitude, longitude}= route.params;    
    const [ butText, setButText] = useState("Apply Now");

 <TouchableOpacity disabled={ clickable } style={page.button} onPress={()=>{
      
     //apply() works fine
      apply(id).then(async (result)=>{
      if(result.succeeded()){
        setButText('Application Successful!');
        setClickable(true);
      }
  });
 }}>
    <Text style={page.text}>{ butText }</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.clickable'). if I use useContext(false) it works but then facing the same issue

Comment: Change `const [clickable, setClickable] = useState(false);`

Comment: also can't hooks be called inside functions only?

Comment: the null error was because of export const clickableContext= createContext(null). it doesn't work if I change it,useState(false) doesn't make a difference

Comment: Edited the hooks

Comment: it doesn't work because createContext Is null;

Comment: It is supposed to be null when created - in the first code snippet. Then it's added in the second using the provider. Have you added the provider somewhere above home.js and job details.js?

Comment: Wrapping your components with the provider makes clickable and setclickable available to all components under/inside this level

Comment: cool thanks. I wrapped  the <provie> around everything opponents in App.js. It wrks now, but when I hit apply on any job, all jobs are disabled but the button text doesn't change either